# Dynamic SOSL with multiple search terms not returning records with email or phone number

Tags: apex, sosl, dynamic-sosl

I am facing couple of challenges with Dynamic SOSL.
Records are available with "test.abc1@test.digital or test.abc@test.com" and "(123) 456-7890"(based on locale).

we are using Dynamic SOSL query with multiple search terms and asterisk match (*)

Email field not working with :-

1. searchTerm ="@test.digital*"
2. searchTerm ="abc1*"
3. searchTerm ="abc1@test.digital*" or searchTerm =".abc1@test.digital*"

Phone number not working with :-

1. searchTerm ="890*"
2. searchTerm ="23)4*"
3. searchTerm ="67890*"

***We want to fetch records with any character from email field and any number from Phone number field.***

we tried multiple ways suggested by salesforce i.e.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_find.htm

Code :-

```
SearchCaseByMultipleId(string searchText){
        String searchTerms = '(';
        for(string str : searchText.split(',')){
            if(str.length()>0){
               searchTerms  = searchTerms+' "' +str +'*'+'" '+'OR';
            }else{                
            }           
        }
        searchTerms = searchTerms.removeEnd('OR');
        searchTerms = searchTerms+')';
       string finalQuery = 'FIND :searchTerms IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING '+objectName+'(' + quryFields +' 
         ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC NULLS last)';
       list<list<Sobject>> results = search.query(finalQuery);
}
```

search term looks like :- ("@test.digital*" OR "abc1*").

Is there any other way for my requirement or is something missing?

Comment: SOSL only supports (exact or wildcarded) matches from the start of the value, so the search term "@test.digital" will never match a value like "example@test.digital". Wilcards cannot appear at the start of the search term either, so you can't do this to try to work around that limitation either. If you are able, consider using SOQL instead.

Comment: Hi Phil W,
Thanks for reply.

but its working fine with the search term like "@test.com".

Comment: Ah, perhaps because the @ is treated as a word separator when the value is indexed. Fair enough.